# How to use ffmpeg with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am super new to Nuxt, and I am currently trying to move over a vue application that generates gifs ffmpeg.wasm to use Nuxt.js. However, whenever I visit the page the server crashes with the following error:

```
[fferr] requested a shared WebAssembly.Memory but the returned buffer is not a SharedArrayBuffer, indicating that while the browser has SharedArrayBuffer it does not have WebAssembly threads support - you may need to set a flag                                                 18:36:38
(on node you may need: --experimental-wasm-threads --experimental-wasm-bulk-memory and also use a recent version)
```

I know it says to add the flags to node, as does the ffmpeg.wasm docs, but how do I do that via Nuxt? Or can I even do that? It is using the default dev server that comes with Nuxt, and I will be able to solve this when it's built and hosted but I need to have it locally as well.

Here is the component I am using in my barebones Vue app (stripped back but still causes an error). I am using node  v14.17.6 and I'm using this library github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/README.md

```html
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <h1>FFMPEG test</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { createFFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data: function () {
        return {
            ffmpeg: null,
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
            log: true,
        })
        // Initialise loadFFmpeg
        this.loadFFmpeg()
    },
    methods: {
        async loadFFmpeg() {
            await this.ffmpeg.load()
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what is your version of node? Do you have the potential buggy code or some configuration to share?

Comment: @kissu I'm using v14.17.6, I'm using this library https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/README.md
Just imported, I've updated the original question with the code I'm using in a barebones vue app

Comment: Looking at this [Vue3 example](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app/blob/main/src/App.vue), it looks like that this is doable at least. Did you try to do the whole thing in `mounted()`? Also, since this needs to be available on client only, maybe try to wrap it inside of `<client-only>` tag as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component

Comment: @kissu You are a wizard! It seems to be working now within mounted(), I know obviously this is called after created, further down the chain, but do you know why this has fixed it? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the instance into a `mounted()` fixed the issue.
This is probably due to the fact that `ffmpeg` needed the Vue instance to be already mounted in the DOM (in the way it works).
`created()` is usually used for AJAX calls or things not so related to the Vue instance, and it being shown with the Composition API in [their example](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app/blob/main/src/App.vue) gave me the idea of trying the `mounted()` hook.